# VM CPU usage at 100%

Tags: monitoring, virtual-machines, docker, graphite

CPU usage on our metrics box is at 100% intermittently causing:
'Internal server error' when rendering Grafana dashboards

The only application running on our machine is Docker with 3 subcontainers

- cadvisor
- graphite
- grafana

**Machine spec**
OS Version Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release 16.04 (xenial)
Kernel Version 4.4.0-103-generic
Docker Version 17.09.0-ce
CPU 4 cores
Memory 4096 MB
Memory reservation is unlimited
Network adapter mgnt

**Storage**
Driver overlay2
Backing Filesystem extfs
Supports d_type true
Native Overlay Diff true

Memory swap limit is 2.00GB

Here is a snippet from cAdvisor:

[image]

The kworker and ksoftirqd processes change status constently from 'D' to 'R' to 'S'

Are the machine specs correct for this setup?
How can I get the CPU usage to 'normal' levels?

**EDIT**

After increasing memory from 4GB to 8GB it worked as expected for a few days but over time the CPU usage increased:
[image]

Comment: Try to increase the memory.

Comment: Try following one liner to find load per container docker ps -q  | xargs docker stats

Comment: @antrost the snippet above gives the same stats per process. The graphite container CPU usage is at 35.5%.

Comment: @Patrick Mevzek  What would the required/expected memory be for the above setup?

Comment: No idea, but I would start by doubling it from what you have, and see if CPU then goes back to normal use.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I increased the memory to 8GB and it worked as expected for a few days but over time the CPU usage increased. I included the CPU usage snippet above

Comment: Long shot, but...   a memory leak with lots of swapping could cause this. If you run top, could you check the load and the waiting metric (wa). Is cpu usage coming from writing to disk? Can you run iotop and check if the process is writing or reading a lot from the disk?

Answer (score 3):

You have 4 ksoftirqds using 39% of your CPU.  That is rather high, and can indicate a number of issues such as high I/O load, problems with power management, or kernel/device driver bugs.

Try updating to the latest kernel, making sure you have the appropriate variant selected (e.g. there are Ubuntu kernels specifically tuned for AWS & Azure), and have a look into some of the Linux I/O performance troubleshooting tools.

A great resource on Linux performance troubleshooting generally is [Brendan Gregg's blog](http://www.brendangregg.com/linuxperf.html)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the kernel is using tons of CPU `kworker` threads which is often caused by a buggy kernel driver.

To debug, trigger a backtrace with `echo l > /proc/sysrq-trigger` which will cause output to be generated in `dmesg`. Run it a few times to see if it's consistent. Based on [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33640/kworker-what-is-it-and-why-is-it-hogging-so-much-cpu) it might be obvious which driver is causing the high load. One thought is if you're running this on ESXi the e1000 network interface driver is notoriously buggy.